# How to display Loading message in my JSP

Tags: jsp, loading

When i click on a button, it goes and executes a batch file on server, which takes considerable time to finish, so i need to display **Please Wait** message on my page, while the process executes in background. I have below code in my JSP.

```
<%
if(session.getAttribute("wait") != null){
        session.removeAttribute("wait");
 %>
// this is 'wait' block
<html>
<head><title>searching...</title>
<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0'>
<style type="text/css">
.wait{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 13px;
color: #ff0000;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" valign="middle">
<tr>
<td class="wait">
Please wait, menus are being searched...
<br>
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" border="0">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<%
}
else{
     session.setAttribute("wait", new String());
%>

// This is where process is executed.
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>List</title>
</head>

<%
    try
        {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start /wait my.bat");
            p.waitFor();
            out.print("The last update was on "+ sdf.format(file.lastModified()));

        }
    catch(Exception ex)
        {
            out.println(ex);
        }
%>

<p>
        <iframe src="../jsp/new_list.txt" frameborder="0" height="80%" width="95%"></iframe>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But what is happening here is, when i click on the button, the process gets executed but no message appears, now when the batch file is finished executing, the request for execution gets fired again and the Wait message appears on the screen. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to use scriptlet in JSP.

There is simple logic to display loading image on click of button.
1.Have hidden loading image
2.On click of button show loading image.
3.When you get response from server hide loading image.

Comment: On button click, this JSP is being called which in turn will execute a batch file, now this batch file takes time in execution and i want a loading image here. Nothing else involved

Comment: I think you need to rework your workflow . Loading images shown at client side at browser, when you call JSP it executes at server side . so before calling jsp show loading image and after execution completes hide loading image.

Comment: The code i added is supposed to do the same, right?
but it is not. And how would i know in caller JSP that the other JSP has finished executing.